# Full path names printed for __FILE__ in VS2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, path, filenames

Our code uses `__FILE__` to print code locations in a log file.
Our intent is for all instances of `__FILE__` to print the filename ONLY, no path.

However, we just noticed that while source (`.cpp` files) correctly print just the filename, the headers (`.h` files) print the full path.  This exposes our build server's path on customer installations, which is confusing at best.

I have researched the [`/FC` (full pathnames)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/027c4t2s%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) compile option and how it relates to the [`/ZI` and `/Zi` (debug info generation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) compile options.  Short version - `/ZI` implies `/FC`.  We are currently using `/Zi`, but we are not using either `/ZI` or `/FC`, so we should be fine.

We are using a project-wide precompiled header (PCH), but none of the headers included in the PCH use `__FILE__`, so that seems irrelevant.

What's going on here?
Is there possibly a latent compile option I'm triggering?
Does anyone know of a workaround that doesn't involve calling run-time string manipulation functions?

Comment: Our solution was to implement a string-trimming function that returns a pointer to the start of the filename substring in a fully-qualified path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is asserted as "by design" in this [feedback article](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/471894/-file-is-being-expanded-to-a-full-path-even-though-the-fc-switch-is-not-being-used).  Consider a post-processing step that hacks the paths the way you want them.

Comment: Thanks for finding that - I missed it in my hour of searching yesterday.  Ugh.  It'd be nice if that was documented anywhere on MSDN.  I think I'll go drop that link into the /FC docs.